# javascript toggle and anchor

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am just starting in javascript, so I need some help. I have a simple javascript that toggles a div on my webpage. The div is working well, but because it is in the footer of the page, it opens and you cannot see the content. How do I make the toggle scroll down so the entire div can be seen?

I found similar examples for other scripts, but have not been able to apply them here.

This is my javascript

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("showindex");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "inherit") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show List";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "inherit";
    text.innerHTML = "Show List";
}
}
```

This is my html

```
            <div id="IndexSlider">
                <a href="#showindex"><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show List</a></a>
            </div>
            <div id="showindex">
                The content here will be several lines of links.
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
ele.scrollIntoView();
```

after setting `display` to "inherit".

It will attempt to scroll the element to the top of the page, but end up scrolling up just as far as it can.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm and brings the entire div into view exactly like I needed.